# Where to insert preventDefault in jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the snippet found at to http://tympanus.net/Development/MorphingSearch/ enlarge a search box when it is clicked..

```
<script>
        (function() {
            var morphSearch = document.getElementById( 'morphsearch' ),
                searchlink = document.getElementById( 'mybtn' ),
                input = morphSearch.querySelector( 'input.morphsearch-input' ),
                ctrlClose = morphSearch.querySelector( 'span.morphsearch-close' ),
                isOpen = isAnimating = false,
                // show/hide search area
                toggleSearch = function(evt) {

                    // return if open and the input gets focused
                    if( evt.type.toLowerCase() === 'focus' && isOpen ) return false;

                    if( isOpen ) {
                        classie.remove( morphSearch, 'open' );

                        // trick to hide input text once the search overlay closes 
                        // todo: hardcoded times, should be done after transition ends
                        if( input.value !== '' ) {
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                classie.add( morphSearch, 'hideInput' );
                                setTimeout(function() {
                                    classie.remove( morphSearch, 'hideInput' );
                                    input.value = '';
                                }, 300 );
                            }, 500);
                        }

                        input.blur();
                    }
                    else {
                        classie.add( morphSearch, 'open' );
                    }
                    isOpen = !isOpen;
                };

            // events
            searchlink.addEventListener( 'click', toggleSearch );
            ctrlClose.addEventListener( 'click', toggleSearch );
            // esc key closes search overlay
            // keyboard navigation events
            document.addEventListener( 'keydown', function( ev ) {
                var keyCode = ev.keyCode || ev.which;
                if( keyCode === 27 && isOpen ) {
                    toggleSearch(ev);
                }
            } );


            /***** for demo purposes only: don't allow to submit the form *****/
            morphSearch.querySelector( 'button[type="submit"]' ).addEventListener( 'click', function(ev) { ev.preventDefault(); } );
        })();
    </script>
```

All works great but as the search box is in a fixed header the page content jumps to the top when the link is clicked.

Previously when this has happened i have inserted the following...

```
   event.preventDefault();
```

I can't work out where to insert this in this code though, can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You insert it in the function that is called by the click event handlers

```
toggleSearch = function(evt) {

    if (evt.type === 'click') {

        evt.preventDefault();

    }

    // rest of code

}

searchlink.addEventListener( 'click', toggleSearch );
ctrlClose.addEventListener( 'click', toggleSearch );
```

Note the condition, it's to make sure the default action isn't prevented when the `keydown` handler is calling the same function

Comment: Thanks, i had tried it there but it was the if statement I was missing